# Make a custom WPF Control Designer friendly

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, wpf-controls

I created a custom control (by extending `System.Windows.Control.Control`) and styled it with `Generic.xaml`

This works well but the only way i have found so far to get it designer friendly is to add the `ContentPropertyAttribute` to specify which property holds the (main) content.

The Designer allows me then to interact with this content like if it is a layout (for example you can click within the content in the Designer preview to select something)

However my control needs to have more than one content area.

And those additional areas do not work well with the Designer. You can specifiy the content in xaml and it is shown correctly, but you cannot interact with it.

Is there a way to get the Designer to support multiple content properties?

**EDIT:** Here is an example of how my control usage should look like:

```xml
<my:MyControl>
  <my:MyControl.HeaderContent>
    <TextBlock Text="Content for Header" />
  </my:MyControl.HeaderContent>
  <my:MyControl.FooterContent>
    <TextBlock Text="Content for Footer" />
  </my:MyControl.FooterContent>
  <TextBlock Text="Main Content (annotated with [ContentProperty])">
</my:MyControl>
```

**EDIT2:** Here is a minmal working example

If you want to give it a try just create a new Wpf Application and add those two files and modify MainWindow.xaml.

Themes/Generic.xaml:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}">
                    <Border BorderThickness="3"  BorderBrush="Blue" CornerRadius="5" Background="White" Padding="5">
                        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                            <Border DockPanel.Dock="Top" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Red" CornerRadius="5" Padding="5">
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding HeaderContent}"  />
                            </Border>
                            <Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Green" CornerRadius="5" Padding="5">
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content1}" />
                            </Border>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

MyControl.cs:

```xml
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    [ContentProperty("Content1")]
    public class MyControl : Control
    {
        static MyControl()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyControl),
                   new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyControl)));
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderContentProperty =
             DependencyProperty.Register("HeaderContent", typeof(object),
             typeof(MyControl), null);

        public static readonly DependencyProperty Content1Property =
             DependencyProperty.Register("Content1", typeof(object),
             typeof(MyControl), null);


        public object HeaderContent
        {
            get { return GetValue(HeaderContentProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(HeaderContentProperty, value);
               // HeaderContentHost.Content = value;
            }
        }
        public object Content1
        {
            get { return GetValue(Content1Property); }
            set {
                SetValue(Content1Property, value);
                //ContentHost.Content = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <local:MyControl>
        <local:MyControl.HeaderContent>
            <Label Background="BlueViolet" Height="100" >
                HeaderContent
            </Label>
        </local:MyControl.HeaderContent>
        <local:MyControl.Content1>
            <Label Background="Yellow">
                Main Content
            </Label>
        </local:MyControl.Content1>
    </local:MyControl>
</Window>
```

And the point is that if you open MainWindow.xaml in the Visual designer you can only interact with Content1 and only if the ContentProperty on the control is present. If you remove the ContentProperty you can neither interact with Content1 nor the HeaderContent.

Does anybody know a way to get such a control more designer friendly?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The `[ContentProperty]` attribute will allow you to add multiple child elements if the type of the property is in fact a collection. If it's not a collection, then why do you think you can add multiple child elements in the XAML? What do you expect the XAML compiler to do with that? Please provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you are trying to do, explain what that code does, and what you want it to do instead, and what _specifically_ you are having trouble figuring out.

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake with my answer, had to retract it

Comment: @PeterDuniho added an example

Comment: This question is really bothering me, since I even tried to copy the `HeaderedContentControl` from official sources with only some small changes and couldn't get the designer to work or (supposedly equivalent) let both, header and content, show up in Blend in the "Objects and Timeline Panel". I'm really wondering whether MS just did a smartass static workaround for their own controls, because nothing about this is documented and nothing seems to work so far.

Comment: Maybe a starting point, maybe off track... decide for yourself: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546938.aspx

Comment: @grek40 This link is indeed interesting, didn't know about those Design extensions. I've spent quite some time digging through all the classes in `Microsoft.Windows.Design.Interaction` but I have not yet found a simple solution. I could implement an AdornerPane which catches alle the mouse events and look up the controls below myself to simulate the default behaviour, but it feels way to complicated to solve this.